# Ansible isn't installing Apache rewrite module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible isn't installing the rewrite module for Apache.

Ansible task:

```
- name: Enable mod_rewrite
  apache2_module:
    state: present
    name: rewrite
```

Taks results:

```
TASK [apache : Enable mod_rewrite] *********************************************
fatal: [local_vm]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Error executing /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: AH00526: Syntax error on line 33 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:\nInvalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration\n"}
```

I noticed that the module wasn't enabled:

```
me@server:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$ ls | grep write
me@server:/etc/apache2/mods-enabled$
```

**Update #1**

Here is the content of mysite.conf:

```
32: # Redirect to https
33: RewriteEngine On
34: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/lightbox
```

Comment: What are the contents of mysite.conf? At least near the offending line.

Comment: Added update 1, indicating line 33 where the issue is.

Comment: So what's the question? It seems Apache complained about the module being unavailable. What does it have to do with Ansible? Does enabling it work from CLI, but not Ansible?

Comment: How can Apache complain that the conf is wrong in the first place as no notify is attached to the task? But more importantly, I want to enable the missing Apache module using the available Ansible module. If I list the content of mods-enabled, the rewrite module is not there. It's under mods-available though. This used to work, however today, I had to change the targeted Apache version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.5 from 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.3). Not sure if this is related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
- name: Enable rewrite module
  apache2_module:
    name: rewrite
    state: present
    ignore_configcheck: True
```

Comment: I'm on 2.2.2 and that option isn't recognized.

Comment: `ignore_configcheck` option is introduced in Ansible 2.3

Comment: Currently using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to run my scripts onto a Virtualbox/Ubuntu VM. I seem to have the latest for Ansible on WSL.

Comment: Nothing else to report other than what has been specified earlier.

Comment: I was able to update Ansible to 2.3 which fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `shell` Ansible module to run the `a2enmod` command. That way you are using Apache's own tool to enable `mod_rewrite`, and you have no dependency on the `apache2_module` Ansible module.

Like this:

```
- name: enable mod_rewrite in apache.
  shell: "a2enmod rewrite"
  register: a2enmodrewrite
  changed_when: "'already enabled' not in a2enmodrewrite.stdout"
```

Also note that in this example I store the output from the command (the `shell` line) with the `register` directive.

I then specify that the task should ***only*** be marked as a change during runtime ***if*** the register contents (accessed with `a2enmodrewrite.stdout`) does not contain 'already enabled'.

So you get `mod_rewrite` enabled and you make sure that when you run the Ansible playbook you are only notified of a change if the module was not already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a template for .conf file and add the rewrites needed. (which is Jinja2 syntax).

Then the contents would be included in the generated Apache VirtualHost file while executing the playbook.